# It is possible to assign it a keyboard shortcut or mnemonic In QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

When using a QLabel in PyQt5, it is possible to give it a **keyboard shortcut or mnemonic** ...

For example :

by setting the text to **"E&xit"**, the **mnemonic is x**, and the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it (it seems for windows only, I am on mac OS) but from Qt documentation you can use setBuddy() to link your QLabel to a QlineEdit for instance:

```
    nameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    nameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("&Name")
    nameLabel.setBuddy(nameEdit)
```

Comment: Its assign with QLineedit only. Just I want to use in Qlabel alone